# Creating process of 3 serial blocks of code

Tags: ios, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I have 3 blocks of code that must execute one by one after previous finished. My implementation not works. I need some help to do it. My code bellow.

```
    for (NSString *i in items)
    {
   [[RequestAPI sharedInstance]downloadImage:i completion:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

     //here main thread I receive images and go to BG

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

       //   here I save image on disk and get path
            NSString *path = [ImageManager saveImageToDisk:image toEntity:entity withparams:@{@"save" : @"lala"}];
          __block  NSMutableDictionary *attachments = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
          __block  NSMutableArray *photoPaths = [NSMutableArray array];



          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           //block1. here I load entity and dictionary from it with NSKeyedUnarchiver from CD and set to it image path
            if (entity.attachments)
            {
                attachments = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:entity.attachments];
                if (attachments[type])
                {
                    photoPaths = attachments[type];
                }
            }

              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

              //block2. here I check all images equality ti themselves  in entity   
            BOOL haveDublicate = NO;
            NSData *i = [ImageManager imageDataFromPath:path];
            NSArray *photoImages = [ImageManager imageDatasFromPaths:photoPaths];
            for (NSData *saved in photoImages)
            {
                if ([saved isEqualToData: i])

                {
                    haveDublicate = YES;
                }
            }

            if (!photoPaths)
            {
                photoPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
            }



                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                   //block3. and finally if all ok I save image path, change load counter and post notification
                             if (path.length
                && ![photoPaths containsObject:path]
                && !haveDublicate
                )
            {
                [photoPaths addObject:path];
                [savedLinks setObject:photoPaths forKey:type];

                entity.attachments = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:savedLinks];

                [self saveContext];
            }
            [RequestAPI sharedInstance].downloadsCount -= 1;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:kReloadFeedData object:nil];



                   });
               });
           });
        });
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

As `dispatch_async` says they will be executed asynchronous and not synchronous as you expected. Use `dispatch_sync` instead.

If you want to execute your code on a separate thread simple do the following

```
// create your thread    
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("My Other Queue", 0);

// execute your synchronous block on the thread you've just created
dispatch_sync(queue,^{

  // add your implementation here to be executed on your separate thread




  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()^{

   // update your UI here. Don't forget you can only update UI on the main thread

  });

});
```

Comment: Do I need to create a group or just enough dispatch_sync implementation ?

Comment: then I do it, it freezes app

Comment: it freezes as you are executing it on the main thread. Please take a look in my answer you will see how to approach this

Comment: but how then can I add thread block between your 2 for background thread?